# How can I remove a dependency between two gesture recognizers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using the code below for testing a solution to long press issues in a WKWebView.

I know how to create a dependency between two gesture recognizer but how can I remove it?

```
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    // Break

    [gestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:otherGestureRecognizer];
}
else {

    // Fix

    // ...
}
```

Assuming something like:

```
[gestureRecognizer shouldntRequireGestureRecognizerToFail:otherGestureRecognizer];
```

or

```
[gestureRecognizer removeDependencies];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
    for (id gestureRecognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers){

        //Compare and Remove which gesture you want
        if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
        {

        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

        }
        else if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Removing the gesture recognizer does in fact remove the dependency.